# tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, su

I have a script in `bash` which connects to a host and on the remote host runs a script which needs root permissions.

I cannot directly login as root (and I don't want to do that) because of security problems.

I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -tt user@host <<SSH 
su - root 
/tmp/script_with_root_permisions.sh
SSH
```

After running I get the following error:

```
 user@hosts's password: #I type the ssh password for user "user"
```

And then:

```
 tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 Last login: Mon Feb 23 13:06:15 2015 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 Password: And here the root password is shown as plain text and the script stops.
```

P.S:  I run this script on Solaris NOT Linux. I saw some workarounds using `sudo` but in Solaris there is no `sudo` command.

Comment: Try `su root -c '/tmp/script_with_root_permissions.sh'` instead. The way you have it written, even assuming `su` can properly control the terminal to acquire the password, your script is not running until after `su` exits... Also, using that approach, you could dispense with the heredoc, and just do it all at once - `ssh -tt user@host su root -c /tmp/script_with_root_permissions.sh`...

Comment: Thanks for response.
I tried both sugested solutions. Same output :(